# Hibernate Search 6 @ProjectionConstructor not working

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, projection, hibernate-search, hibernate-search-6

I am experimenting the projection features of Hibernatesearch 6.2.0.Alpha1 before integrating our existing app.

I have created a spring-boot project with JHIPSTER [sample project](https://github.com/anothergoodguy/spring-data-hibernate-search). And added the Hibernate-search dependencies and configurations in both POM.XML and application*.yml. Using JHipster because it helps me with the boilerplate code and fake data.

Have configured pom.xml with both `-parameters` and `jandex`. Application runs successfully and loads the data into the database. And i am able to mass Index with the utility we wrote as per the documents.

However when try to search the data with projections we are recieving the error `Exception in searchWithProjection() with cause = 'NULL' and exception = 'HSEARCH700112: Invalid object class for projection: com.sample.shop.service.projections.dto.Address. Make sure that this class is mapped correctly, either through annotations (@ProjectionConstructor) or programmatic mapping. If it is, make sure the class is included in a Jandex index made available to Hibernate Search.'`. The same query/logic works perfectly fine if we search without projections.

Ex. if you view the files `AddressResource.java & AddressService.java` in the above linked repository; you can find 2 implementations for projections and no-projections respectively. while the one without projections works perfectly fine the one with projects is throwing the error.

I feel it might be some configuration issue, however not able to figure-out myself. Appreciate your help on configuration / code approach.

Please be informed that I have gone through the follwoing tickets already:

1. [Hibernate Search 6 combine projections not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71801844/hibernate-search-6-combine-projections-not-working)
2. [Single return type in Hibernate Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69735853/single-return-type-in-hibernate-search/69736338?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C10.6766#69736338)

Comment: I would debug your app to see what's going on, but I can't run it. In particular I can't start keycloak for some reason (getting "Could not invoke public void org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.command.ImportRealmMixin.setImportRealm(java.lang.String) with  (java.lang.NullPointerException)"). Can you provide instructions on how to stat your app? Or maybe a smaller reproducer, e.g. a version of your app with security disabled?

Comment: Thank you for your quick checking, I have added a new branch with NO-SSO option.
Here is the direct link for it: https://github.com/anothergoodguy/spring-data-hibernate-search/tree/no-sso. adding the instructions in an aswer item as stackoverflow is not allowing me to add longer texts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your reproducer. It's a bug: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-4724

I suggested a workaround here: https://github.com/anothergoodguy/spring-data-hibernate-search/pull/1

In short:

- Add this class to your application:

```
package com.sample.shop.config;

import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import org.hibernate.search.mapper.orm.mapping.HibernateOrmMappingConfigurationContext;
import org.hibernate.search.mapper.orm.mapping.HibernateOrmSearchMappingConfigurer;
import org.hibernate.search.util.common.jar.impl.JandexUtils;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component("searchMappingConfigurer")
public class HibernateSearchMappingConfigurer implements HibernateOrmSearchMappingConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configure(HibernateOrmMappingConfigurationContext context) {
        // Workaround for https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-4724
        // => Hibernate Search doesn't seem to find the Jandex index in the fat JAR.
        try {
            var classesUri = getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI();
            var ssp = classesUri.getSchemeSpecificPart();
            var jarpath = Path.of(ssp.substring(ssp.indexOf(":") + 1, ssp.indexOf("!")));
            context.annotationMapping().add(JandexUtils.readIndex(jarpath).get());
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

- Reference it in your configuration:

```
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate.search.mapping.configurer: bean:searchMappingConfigurer
```

And voilà.

Note it's just a workaround and relies on internal code that may break at any time. But, well, at least it works, so it's fine until the bug gets fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the instructions to run the application:

All the needed ecosystem like Elasticsearch, kibana and MySql are added in `eco.yml` file under `src/main/docker/eco.yml`
Please use the following command to bring the ecosystem up `docker-compose -f src/main/docker/eco.yml up -d && docker-compose -f src/main/docker/eco.yml logs -f`

On a different termina tab/window, Build the application with the following command  `./mvnw clean package -Pprod,api-docs -Dskip.Tests -Dmaven.test.skip=true`
to run the application run the following command `java -jar target/shop-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Once the application is started, it will show that it's listneing on [[http://localhost:8080]](http://localhost:8080). Please open the same url on the browser and login with the default administrator User:`admin` and Password:`admin`.
Then please navigate to swagger from **Administrator** menu and *API* menu-item.

We need to Mass-Index the fake data that's is already loaded from swagger from same swagger window: by executing the post on **/api/mass/index** on the resource **Elastic Search Mass Indexing API**

Then please go to the **address-resource** :

1. Request without Projections access `/api/_search/addresses` with
   query string `aa` - This will result in success
2. Request with Projections access `/_search/addresses/projection` with same query string `aa` - This will result in failure