# Hibernate Search 6.2.0.Alpha2 Index Problem

Tags: hibernate-search, hibernate-search-6

Upgraded from Hibernate Search 6.2.0.Alpha1 to 6.2.0.Alpha2

No other changes and we are now getting the following runtime error when the application attempts to create the initial indexes.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.search.util.common.SearchException: HSEARCH900013: Exception 
while accessing Jandex index for 
'jar:file:/home/ash/Dev/pins5/pins5/integration/integration-batch- 
service/build/libs/integration-batch-service.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/security-persistence  
-plain.jar!/': HSEARCH900014: Exception while building Jandex index for 
'jar:file:/home/ash/Dev/pins5/pins5/integration/integration-batch- 
service/build/libs/integration-batch-service.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/security-persistence- 
plain.jar!/': HSEARCH900016: Cannot open filesystem for code source at 
'jar:file:/home/ash/Dev/pins5/pins5/integration/integration-batch- 
service/build/libs/integration-batch-service.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/security-persistence- 
plain.jar!/': HSEARCH900018: Cannot open a ZIP filesystem for code source at 
'jar:file:/home/ash/Dev/pins5/pins5/integration/integration-batch- 
service/build/libs/integration-batch-service.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/security-persistence- 
plain.jar!/', because the URI points to content inside a nested JAR.
```

The only changes we have made have been updating our dependencies from

```
 'org.hibernate.search:hibernate-search-mapper-orm:6.2.0.Alpha1'
 'org.hibernate.search:hibernate-search-backend-elasticsearch:6.2.0.Alpha1'
```

to

```
 'org.hibernate.search:hibernate-search-mapper-orm:6.2.0.Alpha2'
 'org.hibernate.search:hibernate-search-backend-elasticsearch:6.2.0.Alpha2'
```

Looking at the release notes I see the following

> Due to switching from new URL(..) to new URI(..) in the Hibernate Search internals > indexing behaviour of URL properties might change. In particular malformed URLs won’t be accepted anymore and would result in a runtime exception.

The hibernate search properties that we set in our yaml are as follows but none of these were changed as part of the upgrade

```
search:
      backend:
             type: elasticsearch
             uris: localhost:9200
             minimal_required_status: yellow
             analysis:
                     configurer: com.saadian.pins.persistence.base.elastic.config.analyzer.CustomAnalyzerProvider
             enabled: true
             schema_management:
                    strategy: create-or-update
             automatic_indexing:
                    enabled: true
                    synchronization:
                        strategy: async
```

Other information the application uses Spring Boot 2.7

Looking at the changes from Alpha1 to Alpha2 the only thing I can see that might possibly have introduced this is the fix for https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-4724

I assume I can probably do something like outlined in [Hibernate Search 6 @ProjectionConstructor not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74149716/hibernate-search-6-projectionconstructor-not-working/74156021#74156021) but would be great if anyone has any guidance on what might be required.

Updating to Spring Boot 2.7.8 makes no difference.

Any help / ideas would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the same scenario. Reasearching in Hibernate search's code, I found this code:

```
private void tryInitJarFileSystem(URI jarUri) throws IOException {
    try {
        nonDefaultFileSystem = FileSystems.newFileSystem( jarUri, Collections.emptyMap() );
        classesPathInFileSystem = nonDefaultFileSystem.getRootDirectories().iterator().next();
        // The ZipFileSystemProvider ignores the "path inside the JAR",
        // so we need to take care of that ourselves.
        String nestedPath = extractedJarNestedPath( jarUri );
        if ( nestedPath != null ) {
            Path nestedPathInFileSystem = classesPathInFileSystem.resolve( nestedPath );
            if ( Files.isRegularFile( nestedPathInFileSystem ) ) {
                // TODO HSEARCH-4744 support reading the content of nested JARs
                throw log.cannotOpenNestedJar( jarUri );
            }
            classesPathInFileSystem = nestedPathInFileSystem;
        }
    }
    catch (RuntimeException | IOException e) {
        new SuppressingCloser( e )
                .push( nonDefaultFileSystem );
        nonDefaultFileSystem = null;
        classesPathInFileSystem = null;
        throw e;
    }
}
```

// TODO HSEARCH-4744 support reading the content of nested JARs

So There is no support for nested JARs in Hibernate 6.2 yet.

In my case, I downgraded to 6.1.8Final.

Comment: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-4744

https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-search/pull/3302/files#diff-34aadb9b7ae241429f0329afd5f984dad24a4345b86a77e9591611db690ab25a

Comment: I have a solution that works. I don’t have access to the code at the moment but I will add it here tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

The following fixed our problem

In your applicationy.yaml or equivalent add the following property

```
hibernate:
   search:
     mapping:
      configurer: com.saadian.pins.persistence.base.elastic.config.mapper.HibernateSearchMappingConfigurer
```

Then we added the following Java class

```
@Component
public class HibernateSearchMappingConfigurer implements HibernateOrmSearchMappingConfigurer {

@Override
public void configure(HibernateOrmMappingConfigurationContext context) {

    context.annotationMapping().buildMissingDiscoveredJandexIndexes(false);
    try {
        URI uri = getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI();
        String schemeSpecificPart = uri.getSchemeSpecificPart();
        Optional<Index> optionalIndex = JandexUtils.readIndex(Paths.get(schemeSpecificPart.substring(schemeSpecificPart.indexOf(":") + 1, schemeSpecificPart.indexOf("!"))).toUri().toURL());
        optionalIndex.ifPresent(index -> context.annotationMapping().add(index));

    } catch (URISyntaxException | MalformedURLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

}

This solved the problem for us at least

Answer (score 0):

Use solve by doing like this :

- properties yml file :
  hibernate.mapping.process_annotations: false
  hibernate.mapping.configurer: com.fallphenix.persistance.common.HibernateSearchMappingConfigurer
- Implementation

```
import org.hibernate.search.mapper.orm.mapping.HibernateOrmMappingConfigurationContext;
import org.hibernate.search.mapper.orm.mapping.HibernateOrmSearchMappingConfigurer;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

public class HibernateSearchMappingConfigurer implements HibernateOrmSearchMappingConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configure(HibernateOrmMappingConfigurationContext context) {
        context.annotationMapping()
                .add(Object1Entity.class)
                .add(Object2Entity.class)
                .add(ObjectNEntity.class)
                .discoverAnnotationsFromReferencedTypes(true)
                .discoverAnnotatedTypesFromRootMappingAnnotations(true);
    }
}
```

Verions bellow :

```
<java.version>17</java.version>
<spring.boot.version>3.1.1</spring.boot.version>
 <hibernate.version>6.2.6.Final</hibernate.version>
<hibernate.search.version>6.2.0.Final</hibernate.search.version>
```